# How can I make interval action with flag in scala cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I need to run IO action on interval if `flag` is set to true. Flag could be set to true multiple times during one interval from other places of program. For example:

```scala
class IntervalAction {
  def touch: IO[Unit] // set flag to true
  
  // if flag is true, on interval do action and set flag to false
} 

class Service(action: IntervalAction) {

  def run = {
    1 to 100 traverse { i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) action.touch()
    }
  }
}
```

How can I implement IntervalAction inner scheduler, interval handler, async flag handler etc with cats?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? Where is the flag? What do you mean by "inner scheduler"? What is "etc"?

Comment: @GaëlJ flag is boolean, if someone called `touch` it sets to true. On interval this flag is checked and if it was "touched" some action happens and timer of interval resets.

Comment: Okay, then what did you try? What are you struggling with? Be more precise. We're not here to write code for you but guide you and help if you have a specific issue.

Comment: @GaëlJ I come with working solution, you could see it in answer. May be you got something to add or see some issues with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come with this solution

```scala
  def backgroundTest: IO[Unit] = {
    var flag = false // probably ok that it is thread-unsafe

    def backgroundInterval: IO[Unit] = {
      IO.println("Interval started") *>
        IO.sleep(3.seconds).flatMap { _ =>
          println(s"3 seconds elapsed flag is: ${flag}")
          flag = false
          backgroundInterval
        }.void
    }
    
    def innerRequestHandler: IO[Unit] = {
      for {
        _ <- IO.println("Write something")
        _ <- IO.readLine
          .flatMap { line =>
            if (line == "q") IO.unit
            else {
              flag = true
              innerRequestHandler
            }
          }
      } yield ()
    }

    backgroundInterval.background.use { _ =>
      innerRequestHandler
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hoping not to sound rude, this code has a lot of problems. Especially the `var`, you want to use a `Ref` instead. Maybe this small example I have here can help you: https://github.com/BalmungSan/programs-as-values/blob/main/src/main/scala/lambda/stream/basics.scala#L85

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You are right about `var`, what else?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In your link `Stream.repeatEval` looks more clear, but I am not sure what happens under the hood, could you compare `Stream.repeatEval` and my example with background?

Comment: Well, your example is not even repeating at all, it just runs once. Overall it was not clear at all what you wanted to do.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No, it is repeting. backgroundInterval repeats every 3 second. innerRequestHandler listens to input, and if it is not `q` changes flag to true.

Comment: Oh right, I see the recursion now, I usually prefer to use things like `foreverM` - Anyways, yeah, if you use a `Ref` for the flag and do `IO.println` rather than a raw `println` inside the `backgroundInterval` then your code would be correct. - Still the `fixedDelay` and `repeatEval` are probably IMHO more clear on the intent. - BTW, minor style, but I would rather do `IO.println` and `IO.readLine` directly than going through `Console[IO]`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, I agree with you. I was in experimentator mode when wrote this XD In real project we decided to use `Stream.repeatEval` and `Ref`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, we just need to tell it what to do when the condition is false:

```
1 to 100 traverse { i =>
  if (i % 2 == 0) action.touch()
  else IO.unit
}
```

Or using a more convenient method:

```
1 to 100 traverse { i =>
  IO.whenA(i % 2 == 0)(action.touch())
}
```

Comment: My question was about IntervalAction inner implementation, scheduler, interval handler, async flag handler etc

Comment: ah I thought it was asking about the fact that the code sample wouldn't compile